# Show that the following vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

> Show that the vectors $\{\sin(x),\cos(x),\sin(x)\cos(x)\}$ in the space of real valued functions defined on $[0,2\pi]$ are **linearly independent**.

We need to show that $$c_1\sin(x)+c_2\cos(x)+c_3\sin(x)\cos(x)=0$$

How would I go about solving this? Would I plug in different values for x in the domain and then try to solve the corresponding system of equations?

Comment: Yes, this is the way - the equation must hold for any $x$. I would set $x=0$ and $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: so if I set x=0 the sin(x) terms will go away since they are equal to 0 and I will bereft with $c_2$=0

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Actually they are linearly independent.

Comment: @Galc127: And that, _by definition_, means that they are linearly independent.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, my bad, I thought that Crostul wrote dependent... Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that
$$
c_1\sin x+c_2\cos x+c_3\sin x \cos x=0,\quad\text{for all}\,\,\,x\in\mathbb R.
$$
Then, setting $x=0$, we obtain that $c_2=0$, while setting $x=\pi/2$, we obtain that $c_1=0$. Thus we are left now with
$$
c_3\sin x \cos x=0,\quad\text{for all}\,\,\,x\in\mathbb R,
$$
which of course implies that $c_3=0$, as well.

**Note.** In general, if $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are distinct real numbers, then the functions
$$
\cos a_1x,\sin a_1x,\ldots,\cos a_nx,\sin a_nx,
$$
are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice direction - Assume the contrary: that there are values $c_1,c_2,c_3$ not all of them $0$, s.t. $c_1\sin(x)+c_2\cos(x)+c_3\sin(x)\cos(x)=0$.

Now look at the value of the function $f(x)=c_1\sin(x)+c_2\cos(x)+c_3\sin(x)\cos(x)$ at $0$ and $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$ to isolate $c_1,c_2$.